# Last step of OpenID verification, always returned "is_valid:false"

Tags: openid, validation, lightopenid

**Problem**  I'm trying to get LightOpenID to work with a Google Apps Enterprise account.  I was getting "No servers found!" when I called validate().  I mocked up a quick page to test each step of LightOpenID and I've gotten a little farther, now always getting "is_valid:false".

**What I've Done So Far**
In working through validate() and discover() line by line, I noticed that certain openid->data[] (think "openid_*") values were not making it into the final params array (think "openid.*") so in my example below I coded those in explicitly.
I can't tell if I'm always getting is_valid:false because I'm missing an openid.*something* value or if because OpenID says the Provider is only supposed to validate each nonce once or something else.

**How You Can Help Me**  If you've gotten this far, I could use one of two things.  Either point out mistake(s) in my sample code or give me a process you've used to test this sort of thing.  Do I really have to logout/back in each time I want to test the validation/verification step?  Are there any tools or processes that speed up this kind of tinkering?

**EXAMPLE CODE** I replaced my domain with example.com.  Let me know if you want any output.
Thanks, Eric B.

```
try {
    $openid = new LightOpenID;
    if(!$openid->mode) {
        if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
            //$openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';
            $openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=example.com';
            header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
        }
?>
<form action="?login" method="post">
    <button>Login with Google</button>
</form>
<?php
    } elseif($openid->mode == 'cancel') {
        echo 'User has canceled authentication!';
    } else {
$tClaimedID = 'https://www.google.com/a/example.com/o8/ud?be=o8';
$openid->data['openid_claimed_id'] = $tClaimedID;

foreach (explode(',',$openid->data['openid_signed']) as $item) {
  $value = $openid->data['openid_'.str_replace('.','_',$item)];
  $params['openid.'.$item] = get_magic_quotes_gpc()?stripslashes($value):$value;
}
$params['openid.mode'] = 'check_authentication';
$params['openid.ns'] = $openid->data['openid_ns'];
$params['openid.signed'] = $openid->data['openid_signed'];
$params['openid.sig'] = $openid->data['openid_sig'];

$tBody2 = $openid->request($tClaimedID,'POST',$params);
echo "\n\n tBody2: ".$tBody2." \n\n";

    }
} catch(ErrorException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

LightOpenID is looking for `/openid` on your server in search of an XRDS document.

Add the following in whatever responds to your `/openid` document:

```
<?php
  header('X-XRDS-Location: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=example.com');
?>
```

The reason it that after you try to log
in, google returns an identity. This identity must be discovered, to
see if it points at the valid openid provider (so that it's not
spoofing them). Since Gogole returns identities in your domain, you
have to add an information that Google is authorized to issue them.
The information must be at `/openid`, since
the identities are in the form: `http://example.com/openid?[...]`.
Otherwise, LightOpenID opens that url, sees nothing pointing at any
server, and returns "No servers found!".

Comment: Thanks, Mewp!  Straight from the source.  Unfortunately, I'm working on intranet.<my domain>.com and do not have direct access to <my domain>.com  Is it okay to regsub openid.identity to intranet.<my domain>.com?id=123 and host the openid file on intranet.<my domain>.com?  It isn't working yet and I'm worried that the Google OpenID signed fields are tied to <my domain>.com.  Thanks.

Comment: Google will return an identity in form `https://{$site_xrds}/openid?[...]`. Unfortunately, if there's no XRDS document at this url, it's not possible to verify that google has the right to return that identity. So either change your site-xrds to intranet.<your-domain>.com, or persuade whoever has the control of <your-domain>.com to put the X-XRDS-Location header in `/openid`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am facing same problem and solve it :), you should need to disable safe mode : off, that's working for me :)